# c# - erase string if its not found in another string

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I cannot get this to work, its close, but not working :D
My logic here seems to be a bit off, can someone help me out?
What i am trying to achieve is: check if string2 contains a word that does not exist in string1. if this kind of word is found, print it out, and delete it

```
string[] string1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
string[] string2 = { "1", "2", "3", "hello" };

foreach (var var2 in string2)
{
   foreach (var var1 in string1)
   {
      if (!var1.Equals(var2))
      {
         Consoleprint(var2); //print out the string that does not exist in string1[]... which is "hello"
         var2.Replace(var2, ""); //erase the unmatched string
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're looping through every value in both arrays and comparing them. Your second loop needs to loop through everything before it assumes the value doesn't exist. However this can also be reduced to a single line using [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-6.0): `string2.Except(string1)`.

Comment: Also you can't remove an item from an array without re-creating the array. Look into using [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) instead.

Comment: C# 2.0 is from 2006 - is that tag (or some of the others) *really* appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to `for` loop; note that you should change the *item of the array*, `string2[i] = ""`, not loop variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string2.Length; ++i)
  if (!strings1.Contains(string2[i])) {
    // Let's print array item before it will be "erased"
    Consoleprint(string2[i]);

    string2[i] = "";
  }
```